# Add a keyboard shortcut for ask a question

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

SE has a fairly good keyboard shortcut system. It's served me fairly well during this period of me not being able to left-click anything. You can navigate to /questions, /users, meta, the tour... etc.

One thing that seems to be missing, though, is a keyboard shortcut to /questions/ask. This is an important page, and it's a *bit* inconvenient to have to go <kbd>tab</kbd>bing through the page to find it (or manually typing it in the URL bar).

I'd suggest that the keyboard shortcut, to be consistent with the other ones, be <kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd>. No other keyboard shortcut is currently using the <kbd>A</kbd> key, and it seems a logical choice for "ask".

And, of course, don't forget to add it to the auto-help ;)

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good feature to have, so, until this is properly implemented, I've made a very simple JavaScript fix using the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/related?hl=en) extension.

1. Download the aforementioned extension.
2. Click "Create new script" as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

3. Copy and paste this exact code into the area that will come up (there should be a comment prompting you to paste it in):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Keyboard shortcut to ask a question
// @author       Ollie
// @match       *://*stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           *://*serverfault.com/*
// @match           *://*superuser.com/*
// @match           *://*askubuntu.com/*
// @match           *://*stackapps.com/*
// @match           *://*mathoverflow.net/*
// ==/UserScript==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

$(document).keypress("Q",function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey)
        window.location.href = "/questions/ask";
});
})();
```

4. Hit save.  Keep all the `@match`'es to hit all websites on Stack Exchange.  Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> keys to visit the Ask Question page.

And there you are!  Enjoy.