# Why does this question appear twice in this search?

Tags: support, search, stackexchange.com

I made a [search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=keyboard+shortcut+to+ask+question) in the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/search), and the question I was searching for, [Add a keyboard shortcut for ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318670/add-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-ask-a-question), appeared twice:

[image]

That question has no answers.  It has not been posted twice, as far as I know.  Exactly the same: tags, title, site and all.  Why is this?  Is it by design?

It's also not the only one; [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346802/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-follow-questions-answers) one appears twice as well, among others.

Comment: It's not the only one that appears twice.

Comment: After a quick glance at the results it seems to be only the Meta SE questions that are duplicated.

Comment: The same thing happens cross network on sites such as MathSE while Dupe Flagging

Comment: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAE62.png) is example 3

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein Good point!  I saw that too.  The dupe flagging, I mean.